# Event handling in classes

Tags: vb.net, events

I'm completely confused about the event handling. I read some articles about it but after it I just get confused to write and use them in my classes.

This is my class i. e.:

```
Public Class Test
  Public Event playedEvent()

  Public Sub playTimer()
    RaiseEvent playedEvent()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Friend WithEvents t as Test

Private Sub AnEvent() Handles t.playedEvent()
  'Do some stuff
End Sub
```

I dont have any argument passing. But I want to know how should I do it too. And I wanted to know if each instance of the Test class, run this event separately I mean each instance by themselves, This event **AnEvent()** will occur? Cuz I have lots of instances from my class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every instance of class `Test` will have it's own event and you can handle them separately. If you e.g. want to add the instance of `Test` as parameter to the event, you have to change the event declaration in the following way:

```
Public Event playedEvent(t as Test)
```

Then you can raise it:

```
RaiseEvent playedEvent(Me)
```

and handle it:

```
Private Sub AnEvent(t as Test) Handles t.playedEvent()
  't is the actual instance of Test
End Sub
```

Here are more informations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkzf914z.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
Public Event OnDisplayViewModeChange(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal displayMode As DisplayViewMode)



Public Sub UpdateDisplayMode(ByVal displayMode As DisplayViewMode)
        DataViewMultiView.ActiveViewIndex = Convert.ToInt32(displayMode)
        RaiseEvent OnDisplayViewModeChange(Me, displayMode)
End Sub
```